# OnSuccess of JQ navigate user to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Evening All,
I have a Jquery function running from my aspx page (When a button is clicked).
It runs a [webmethod] which if successful returns to the 'OnSuccess' function.
From here I want to navigate the user to: /Project/Invoices/List.aspx

```
 function Onsuccess(CommentSuccessfullyUpdated) {
        if (CommentSuccessfullyUpdated == "TRUE") {
            window.location = Invoices/List.aspx //My attempt, but unsuccessful
        }
        else {
            alert("Invoice/Details- Error: Removing Invoice.");
        }
    }
```

I think its something to do with window.location but this is as far as I have got.....
Any ideas?

Comment: `TRUE` doesn't exist as a keyword in JS. `true`, all lowercase is the correct usage.

Comment: CommentSuccessfullyUpdated is a string which I have set to return TRUE or FALSE from the webmethod(this part works fine) I just need help with the window.location = Invoices/List.aspx part...thanks

Comment: Don't you need to wrap your url in quotes? either `"` or `'` giving `window.location = 'Invoices/List.aspx';`

Comment: window.location = 'Invoices/List.aspx' <-- with quotes

Answer (score 0):

Your List.aspx page **URL need to be enclosed in quotes**, either `"  "` or `'  '`.

```
if (CommentSuccessfullyUpdated == "TRUE") {
    window.location = 'Invoices/List.aspx';
}
```